# Magento: Fatal error: Class?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I install this module to magento:

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/addshoppers-viral-product-sharing-2577.html
```

and have problem with my website now:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Clearcode_Addshoppers_Model_Mysql4_Setup' not found in /data/web/virtuals/49508/virtual/www/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php on line 234
```

could you please help me?
Very Very thank you!

Comment: It sounds like it didn't install properly. You'll need to contact the people that made the extension for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `app/code/<local or community>/Clearcode/Addshoppers/Model/Mysql4/Setup.php` exist at all? if it doesn't, you're missing that file. If it does not then try taking a look inside that file and see if the class name is `Clearcode_Addshoppers_Model_Mysql4_Setup` and not something else.

Answer (score 0):

Path

```
includes/src
```

indicated that magento is looking for class in compiled files directory.
Try to run

```
php shell/compiler.php compile
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have the compiler enabled but it cannot find the (flattened) file.

So either disable the compiler:

php shell/compiler.php disable
Or run a compilation so that it will generate the file for you:

php shell/compiler.php compile